# How to replace part of an input value?

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an input field where the user can post a link to a facebook page. Right now I am using regex to validate the URL.

```
URL_regex = /\A(http|https|ftp):\/\/([\w]*)\.([\w]*)\.(com|net|org|biz|info|mobi|us|cc|bz|tv|ws|name|co|me)(\.[a-z]{1,3})?/i
```

I only want the following four versions to pass the validation:

- `https://www.facebook.com/redbull`
- `http://www.facebook.com/redbull`
- `www.facebook.com/redbull`
- `facebook.com/redbull`

Then I want to only want to store the "redbull" part in the database. I tried [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/) but I can't figure out the logic of the regex.

Thanks in advance

**Found a solution, thx to caley:**

```
  URL_regex = /\A((http|https):\/\/)?(www\.)?facebook\.com\/([\S]+)/i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match only the 4 variants you suggested, plus `http://facebook.com/redbull` and `https://facebook.com/redbull` as these may also be common variants.

```
/\A((http|https):\/\/)?(www\.)?facebook\.com\/(\w*)?/i
```

Answer (score 1):

You already got nice answers for regular expressions, but I wanted to point out the `URI` module:

```
>> require 'uri' 
#=> true
>> uri = URI.parse "https://www.facebook.com/redbull" 
#=> #<URI::HTTPS:0x000001010a41a8 URL:https://www.facebook.com/redbull>
>> uri.scheme 
#=> "https"
>> uri.host 
#=> "www.facebook.com"
>> uri.path 
#=> "/redbull"
```

Maybe validating the individual parts is easier than one big regex.

Answer (score 0):

Without RegEx you can use it:

```
var your_url = ''; //here, you place your URL

console.log(your_url.slice(your_url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
```

This will give desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You just need to add another capture group.

```
\A(http|https|ftp):\/\/([\w]*)\.([\w]*)\.(com|net|org|biz|info|mobi|us|cc|bz|tv|ws|name|co|me)\/(\w+)?
```

or

```
(http|https:ftp:\/\/)?\w*.\w+.(com|net|org|biz|info|mobi|us|cc|bz|tv|ws|name|co|me)\/(\w+)

irb(main):014:0> if x =~ /\A(http|https|ftp):\/\/([\w]*)\.([\w]*)\.(com|net|org|biz|info|mobi|us|cc|bz|tv|ws|name|co|me)\/(\w+)?/
irb(main):015:1> puts $5
irb(main):016:1> end
redbull
=> nil
```